# wget to download new wildcard files and overwrite old ones

Tags: linux, cron, download, ubuntu-12.04, wget

I'm currently using wget to download specific files from a remote server. The files are updated every week, but always have the same file names. e.g new upload **file1.jpg** will replace local **file1.jpg**

This is how I am grabbing them, nothing fancy :

```
wget -N -P /path/to/local/folder/ http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/remote/files/file1.jpg
```

This downloads file1.jpg from the remote server if it is newer than the local version then overwrites the local one with the new one.

Trouble is, I'm doing this for over 100 files every week and have set up cron jobs to fire the 100 different download scripts at specific times.

Is there a way I can use a wildcard for the file name and have just one script that fires every 5 minutes for example?

Something like....

```
wget -N -P /path/to/local/folder/ http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/remote/files/*.jpg
```

Will that work? Will it check the local folder for all current file names, see what is new and then download and overwrite only the new ones? Also, is there any danger of it downloading partially uploaded files on the remote server?

I know that some kind of file sync script between servers would be a better option but they all look pretty complicated to set up.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the files to be downloaded one by one in a text file, and then pass that file name using option `-i` or `--input-file`.

e.g. contents of `list.txt`:

```
http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/remote/files/file1.jpg
http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/remote/files/file2.jpg
http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/remote/files/file3.jpg
....
```

then

```
wget .... --input-file list.txt
```

Alternatively, If all your *.jpg files are linked from a particular HTML page, you can use recursive downloading, i.e. let `wget` follow links on your page to all linked resources. You might need to limit the "recursion level" and file types in order to prevent downloading too much. See `wget --help` for more info.

```
wget .... --recursive --level=1 --accept=jpg --no-parent http://.../your-index-page.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 1) No the files aren't linked from an html page so that option isn't relevant for me. 2) Wouldn't your first method simply download all of those files every time I fired the script regardless of whether the remote ones were newer than the local ones? Or would using wget -N fix that? Also would it download partial files doing it this way?

Comment: Yes with option 1 you would need your existing options `-N` to not download unless newer, `-P` for output prefix, and possibly other options you already have. I meant to imply that with the `....`